# How to create a text file with a MCU and transfer it to PC via USB?

Tags: filesystems, usb, spi, flash-memory

I wish to :

1. Collect data with my ATxmega128A4U (done)
2. Store that data into a text file (.txt)
3. Send the text file to flash storage (via SPI)
4. Connect the flash storage(or MCU?) to PC via USB as a Mass storage controller(MSC)
5. Read the text file on the PC

I have all the data I need on my MCU. I have looked at ATMEL's [file system management](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc7824.pdf) here. I am not sure if this works with my xmega128a4u or where to get the files from. Also, If I use the command "fopen", where is this file stored?

The main issue is creating the text file. Where is it stored after using "FILE *file fopen..."